# Question about recognizing a gesture while touching the screen once in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Hello I wrote a code that uses Gesture recongnizing to turn the pages of a book or change the screen of a book to full screen when touched.

```
fileprivate func setupTap() {
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(webViewTapped))
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        tap.delegate = self
        webView?.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        webView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    @objc func webViewTapped() {
        setupHiddenView()
    }
```

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {

        let prePagePoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self.view)
        let nextPagePoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self.view)
        let fullscreenPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self.view)

        if prePageTapView.frame.contains(prePagePoint) {
            userDefaults.set("p", forKey: UserDefaults.Keys.pageTapped)
        } else if nextPageTapView.frame.contains(nextPagePoint) {
            userDefaults.set("n", forKey: UserDefaults.Keys.pageTapped)
        } else if fullscreenTapView.frame.contains(fullscreenPoint) {
            userDefaults.set("f", forKey: UserDefaults.Keys.pageTapped)
        }
      return true
    }
```

```
fileprivate func setupHiddenView() {
        if userDefaults.string(forKey: UserDefaults.Keys.pageTapped) == "f" {

            print("FULL SCREEN MODE.")

        } else if userDefaults.string(forKey: UserDefaults.Keys.pageTapped) == "p" {
            print("Previous Page")
            //code
        } else if userDefaults.string(forKey: UserDefaults.Keys.pageTapped) == "n" {
            print("Next Page")
            //code
        }
    }
```

When I first entered the view of reading a book, only one touch event occurred when I touched once.

But the problem is, you can watch rewarded ads and read the book for free.
  If you enter the screen for viewing a book again from the screen for viewing rewarded advertisements, two touch events occur for one touch.

After watching the rewarded advertisement 5 times, if you touch it once, 5 touch events will occur. It seems that whenever I enter the rewarded ad screen, `gestureRecognizer (_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer)-> Bool` function seems to have a problem.

What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: Where are you running the `setUpTap()` method?  Is it in `viewWillAppear` or similar as it sounds like it is being run every time the view appears, and that will add multiple gesture recognisers and result in the behaviour you are experiencing?

Comment: Provide a minimal code that can be run to reproduce the issue. It will help debug and provide quick answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get the location of the gesture recognizer you should not get it from a delegate. Instead, you should pass the gesture from action as follow.

```
    @objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {

        let prePagePoint = sender.location(in: self.view)
        let nextPagePoint = sender.location(in: self.view)
        let fullscreenPoint = sender.location(in: self.view)

        if prePageTapView.frame.contains(prePagePoint) {
            userDefaults.set("p", forKey: UserDefaults.Keys.pageTapped)
        } else if nextPageTapView.frame.contains(nextPagePoint) {
            userDefaults.set("n", forKey: UserDefaults.Keys.pageTapped)
        } else if fullscreenTapView.frame.contains(fullscreenPoint) {
            userDefaults.set("f", forKey: UserDefaults.Keys.pageTapped)
        }

 //       Handle event
    }
```

and then set it as

```
   let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:)))
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        tap.delegate = self
        webView?.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```